# Magento 2.3 - Hel to change "const CUSTOM_CARRIER_CODE = 'custom';"

Tags: php, magento, tracking, magento-2.3

would anyone be able to suggest a method or modification to replace the "custom" value with a different word? E.g. from "custom" to "Fantasy Shipping".

The "custom" value is proposed in Magento 2.3 whenever the title is not valued. I would like to be able to replace "custom" value with the custom one every time the field is empty.

Do you think it's enough to modify the value in: magento2/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Track.php (line 25)

```
/**
 * @method \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track _getResource()
 * @method \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Shipment\Track getResource()
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Track extends AbstractModel implements ShipmentTrackInterface
{
    /**
     * Code of custom carrier
     */
    const CUSTOM_CARRIER_CODE = 'custom';
```

Thanks to anyone who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a new module

Step 2: Add the module configuration

Step 3: Create the carrier model

Step 4: Enable the module

Run the commands below to register the Vendor_CustomShipping module:

> bin/magento module:enable Vendor_CustomShipping
>
> bin/magento setup:upgrade

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout-add-custom-carrier.html

Comment: Thanks for the link you shared.

Unfortunately, my problem is with an external module that does not allow custom forwarders to pass through.

This module can't fill the forwarder name field and Magento inserts the "custom" value as default.
I would like to be able to replace the "Custom" value with my own custom label. Do you have any suggestions on this?
Thank you very much.